# Float a div before elder sibling

Tags: css, floating, siblings

Is it possible to have a floated element floated before it's elder sibling?

For example imagine three floated divs:

```
A B C
```

I want them to appear as:

```
A C B
```

I don't want to change the html mark-up becuase this is a responsive design. At a particular break point I want the order of the floats and hence the layout to change.

I have been reading about :after and :before but I'm not sure if this will help me.

```
.myFloat{
    width:75px;
    height:75px;
    margin:10px;
    border:1pc solid #333;
    float:left;
}
```

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ewfMT/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enjoy!
http://jsfiddle.net/ewfMT/1/

```
.myFloat{
    width:75px;
    height:75px;
    margin:10px;
    border:1pc solid #333;
    float:left;
}
.myFloat:nth-child(2) {
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

A basic description of why this works: `float:left` will take an element and stack it to the left of your items, while `display:inline-block` will naturally flow left-to-right, but to the right of all `float:left` elements.

Comment: Tested on firefox 29 and Chromium

Answer (score 0):

Look into the flexbox model. You can reorder the elements there. See http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend flexbox just yet. Support is still fragmented.

Comment: @j08691 Looks like the support is good unless you have to support IE < 11: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: @AlanA Much more flex with flex. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

What about using  Javascript and AJAX (or Jquery) to change the contents of the div's on the fly depending on what content you want to be in them.

Thus even though the order is still A B C  - A really has B's content now in it, or whatever content you want.

So you might do some javascript like this

```
<script>
target = document.getElementById('A');  // this assumes the target div has an ID of "A"
target.innerHTML = "whatever content you want to put in here"
</script>
```

Comment: _"I don't want to change the html mark-up becuase this is a responsive design."_

Comment: @Lrone thanks I did consider that method but for this case it had to be a css only solution